# Use HttpRequest in validation context

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpcontext

in .net Framework <= 4.7.2, in validation context, you could get the current `HttpRequest` by accessing the `HttpContext`.

For example, I had a piece of code which looked like this:

```
public sealed class AccessValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        // validate stuff, if all true -> yield ok.

        // if is not valid
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        // store/log the request payload.
    }

}
```

This cannot be done when using .net Core 2.1. 
I saw a post regarding injection of `IHttpContextAccessor` or something, but it exposes the request in almost every place.

Since this is an external library to my server, I wish it not rely on server code injections because then it creates a dependence I don't want to be.

Is there any known way to handle this or around this?

Comment: I believe the negative modding is no longer valid and this is a legitimate question with legitimate answers.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this with a combination of [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [`ValidationContext.GetService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.getservice?view=netcore-2.1). Here's what it would look like:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    // validate stuff, if all true -> yield ok.

    // if is not valid
    var httpContextAccessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)context.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
    var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

    // store/log the request payload.
}
```

Rather than using dependency injection, it uses the Service Locator pattern ([considered an *anti*-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), but it might be your only real option here).

You'll also need to configure `IHttpContextAccessor` with the DI container in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, like this:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: but that creates a dependency on the server's code. doesn't it?
or the services.AddHttpContextAccessor can be written somewhere in the library?

Comment: Yes, you need to call `AddHttpContextAccessor` in the ASP.NET Core project itself. If you're really trying to avoid that, you're going to struggle... What is wrong with that "dependency", as you call it?

Comment: @OriRefael: How is that less of a dependency then calling static `HttpContext.Current` in previous versions? XD. Also you can register `AddHttpContextAccessor` in your libraries `AddMyLibrary` extension method, so its opaque to your libraries consumers

Comment: In previous framework, you depnded on the fact that youre in http score, which was obvious if you used validation attribute on server. This requires code to be written on server just to make an external reference to work..